# ReactJS Warning: Thumbnails.shouldComponentUpdate(): Returned undefined instead of a boolean value. Make sure to return true or false

Tags: reactjs

I am doing a conditional in my shouldComponentUpdate method and if the condition matches return true, else return false... however I am still getting a "returned undefined instead of a boolean ..." as the title suggests.

Here is my method: * Note if I don't have the setTimeout it automatically assumes that nextProps.props.length is 0 even when its more than 0

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log(nextProps.props, nextProps.props.length);
        if(nextProps.props.length > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
},1000)
}
```

Comment: why you have used `setTimeout` ?

Comment: what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: it was returning as length 0 without the setTimeout regardless if the length was actually 0. Saw that in another solution. I figured it out though, I just had to use this.state in shouldcomponentupdate not this.props or nextProps ... So this question is solved ... now another problem though

Comment: another problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Your components props are actually stored in `nextProps` argument. It seems you're trying to access `props` in `nextProps`, which obviously looks fishy.

You should never name a prop of a component as generic as `props`, if that's really what you're trying to achieve. Give your component's props more descriptive names.

Also, the expression in `shouldComponentUpdate` can be simplified to:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    return nextProps.props.length > 0; // assuming nextProps.props is an array
}
```

Additionally, you should post your component's `propTypes` definition, so the component's props contract is clear.