# shouldComponentUpdate(): Returned undefined instead of a boolean value.

Tags: reactjs

Before anyone marks this as a duplicate, I went through this question 
[ReactJS Warning: Thumbnails.shouldComponentUpdate(): Returned undefined instead of a boolean value. Make sure to return true or false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351446/reactjs-warning-thumbnails-shouldcomponentupdate-returned-undefined-instead) and it doesn't answer my question (or I wasn't able to get it (to say the least)

so this my code

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log(this.props.order, nextProps.order)
    if (nextProps.order !== this.props.order) {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Here when I check the console log in chrome, it throws a warning saying

> shouldComponentUpdate(): Returned undefined instead of a boolean
>   value. Make sure to return true or false

But everything works as expected (or the way I want to), Also when I do something like

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log(this.props.order, nextProps.order)
      return nextProps.order !== this.props.order
  }
```

It doesn't throw an error.

**[Question]** Why am i getting that warning? when I clearly return true?

Comment: add `else return false` after if, you only returned true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting an error in the first case 
because you are not returning anything
if (nextProps.order == this.props.order).
so, you could have done this:

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log(this.props.order, nextProps.order)
    if (nextProps.order !== this.props.order) {
      return true;
    }
    return false; //this is the missing piece
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In second variant it will definitely return **true** or **false**. But in your first piece of code, you don't specify **else** and it can be **true** or **undefined**, so you get that warning

Answer (score 0):

When `nextProps.order !== this.props.order` is false the shouldComponentUpdate function dont enter in the if with return and will return undefined.

shouldComponentUpdate only want to return boolean values.

Try with your second impmenentation to return true or false.